# Spring path variable url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have a request mapping as below

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{city}/{category}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Now spring security OAuth URL also get directed to the above mapping

```
"/oath/token"
```

How do I prevent this or Any suggestion to make "/{city}/{category}" more specific.

PS:- "/resources/manifest.json" is also getting directed to same.

Comment: Your question need to be improved. Provide more details about the problem and follow the community standards for formatting.

Comment: Your Controller has no mapping at all, add `@RequestMapping("/address")` and then access it through `/address/{city}/{category}` in this way it won't conflict with existing, also please choose path and pattern correctly `/{city}/{category}` is very abstract path decision

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change you naming convention, because when you use two path parameters one by one in your path it's like two wildcards /*/* anything can match that URL.

When you create RESTful application you should follow the REST naming convention. In your case it should be:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "cities/{cityId}/categories/{categoryId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

REST naming convention explained:
https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/